# Evolution options in Online Accounts dialog for Google Account

Tags: evolution, online-accounts

I have my Google Apps account setup in Online Accounts, mainly for use with Empathy. This has been working fine for a while. Since updating to 14.04, some new options for Evolution have appeared in the dialog:

[image: Online Accounts - Evolution options]

Since I don't use Evolution, I turned all of these off. But after clicking 'Grant Access' I get:

[image: Online Accounts - prompt]

What features will this enable on my Ubuntu desktop, and why am I still prompted for this even after disabling the integration? If they lead to some thing like new mail notification, or things appearing on the Calender, I might turn them on. But if not, I don't want to give a program I don't use access to my mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Evolution Data Server [GitHub](https://github.com/GNOME/evolution-data-server):

"The Evolution Data Server package provides a unified backend for programs that work with
contacts, tasks, and calendar information. It was originally developed for Evolution
(hence the name), but is now used by other packages as well.

The Evolution Data Server provides a single database for common, desktop-wide information,
such as a user's address book or calendar events.

By using the evolution-data-server, other GNOME applications are integrating with Evolution.

- gnome-panel calendar applet lists your appointments and tasks.
- Synchronize your Pidgin buddies with your Evolution contacts.
- View Planner files as Evolution task lists."

To answer your specific question, you do not have to use Evolution to take advantage of the features provided by Evolution Data Server such as notifications in the dash/calendar applet.

Best,

Lev